# Classy-Prelude (head . head)

Tags: haskell, classy-prelude

I'm trying to convert several projects to [`classy-prelude`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude-0.8.0) at the moment. While most behaviour seems quite straightforward to me, the `(head . head)` gives mysterious errors on a simple 2D list.

Consider the following GHCi session:

```
Prelude> (head . head) [[1,2],[3,4]]
1
```

Let's try this with `ghci -XNoImplicitPrelude` and `classy-prelude`:

```
> import ClassyPrelude
ClassyPrelude> (head . head) [[1,2],[3,4]]

<interactive>:10:1:
    Couldn't match type `MinLen (Succ nat1) mono1' with `[[t0]]'
    Expected type: [[t0]] -> Element mono0
      Actual type: MinLen (Succ nat1) mono1 -> Element mono0
    The function `head . head' is applied to one argument,
    but its type `MinLen (Succ nat1) mono1 -> Element mono0'
    has only one
    In the expression: (head . head) [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
    In an equation for `it': it = (head . head) [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

I assume GHC simply can't resolve the types for multidimensional lists correctly. Is there any way I can help it without resorting to `(Prelude.head . Prelude.head)`?

Comment: `MinLen (Succ nat1) mono1` => I think you need a non-empty list type there

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Where exactly do you think I need a non-empty list? `[[1,2],[3,4]]` is non-empty in both dimensions, and GHC *should* be able to derive an Int type from it (it can do it for `Prelude.head`)

Comment: @UliKöhler I think MauricioScheffer is right. Those lists are non-empty, but their *type* is not a "non-empty list" type.

Comment: @DanielWagner Do you mean that while `Prelude.head`, being a [Partial function](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_functions), fails with `error` on non-empty lists, `classy-prelude` tried to solve this problem by defining non-empty lists as a different types?

Comment: I think that's exactly correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, classy prelude's [head](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-MinLen.html#v%3ahead) function only works on traversables which are guarranted to have at least one element by the type-system, so that it doesn't have to be partial. Because all your lists have at minimum one element, you can just use the non-empty list type:

```
head . head $ mlcons (mlcons 1 $ mlcons 2 $ toMinLenZero []) $ mlcons (mlcons 3 $ mlcons 4 $ toMinLenZero []) $ toMinLenZero [] :: Int
-- 1
```

(The functions starting with `ml` are all from the [MinLen](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-MinLen.html) module of `mono-traversable`, which is reexported by `classy-prelude`)

If you just want the behaviour of the `Prelude.head` function, you can use [unsafeHead](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#v%3aunsafeHead) again from the `mono-traversable` package and exported by default:

```
unsafeHead . unsafeHead [[1,2],[3,4]]
-- 1
```

There is also `headMay` in that module, which can be used if you like to handle failure differently and not crash the whole program.

Comment: Great answer, I'd just throw in `headEx` as well. The difference between that and `unsafeHead` is that `unsafeHead` may cause a segfault with certain datatypes (`Vector` and `ByteString` in particular), whereas `headEx` is guaranteed to throw an exception on an empty container.